# Randoms numbers on iPhone

Tags: iphone, random

What is better? I have the prioritized in the order of "goodness", am I correct?

1. arc4random
2. randmom
3. rand

1 - best, 3 - worst

I need a really good randmon number gen for a lowe number (< 50), so I using % 50 to obtain numbers below 50.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

*I'm pretty sure **randMOM** is the one to use.*

Oh, well, [first google hit](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2008/10/random-thoughts-rand-vs-arc4random.html).

If you need a number in the range [n, m), the *very best approach* is to use a function explicitly designed to do so. Both scaling (from say [0, 1)) and applying a modulus may slightly alter the distribution. Of course, such skewing may be entirely irrelevant (and for most applications is probably only a theoretical consideration) -- especially if only a basic PRNG is employed.

Comment: Hmm, arc4random gives much bigger distribution, hence is this sense it  is better. From the docs:

Description

The arc4random() function uses the key stream generator employed by the arc4 cipher, which uses 8*8 8 bit S-Boxes. The S-Boxes can be in about (2**1700) states. The arc4random() function returns pseudo-random numbers in the range of 0 to (2**32)-1, and therefore has twice the range of rand(3) and random(3) .